# AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute "device"

Tags: python, pytorch

```
---> 13 device = torch.device({"cuda"} if torch.cuda.is_available() else {"cpu"})
     14
     15

AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'device'
```

I'm 99% sure this is because I didn't upgrade pytorch from 0.31 to 0.4 however I can't upgrade pytorch for now.

I need to translate .device (0.4) to something that works in 0.31.

I check the [migration document](https://pytorch.org/2018/04/22/0_4_0-migration-guide.html)  however it doesn't provide how I can convert torch.device in retrospect. Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`torch.cuda.device()` is a context manager.

```
torch.cuda.set_device(0)
# On device 0
with torch.cuda.device(1):
    print("Inside device is 1")    
    # On device 1
print("Outside is still 0")
# On device 0
```

And the above works from 0.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.5

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda:0")
    print("running on the GPU")
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")
    print("running on the CPU")
```